# Como mostrar e ocultar opções conforme a seleção do formulário?

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou criando um site onde vou executar um script que mostre uma lista de opções conforme a seleção do usuário.

Pesquisando na internet achei esse script:

```js
residencial_lista = new Array("Casa", "Apartamento", "kitchenette/conjugados", "Flat", "Loft", "Terreno");
comercial_lista = new Array("Casa", "Apartamento", "kitchenette/conjugados", "Box/garagem", "Cj. comercial/sala", "Galpão/depósito/armazém", "Terreno");
rural_lista = new Array("Chácara", "Sítio", "Fazenda", "Terreno");
lazer_lista = new Array("Casa", "Apartamento", "kitchenette/conjugados", "Flat", "Loft", "Pousada");

function inicio(formulario_nome, select_nome, lista_nome) {
  var select_alvo = document.forms[formulario_nome][select_nome];
  var lista = residencial_lista;
  select_alvo.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    var nome_opcao = lista[i];
    select_alvo.options[i] = new Option(nome_opcao);
  }
}

function trocarSelect(formulario_nome, select_nome, lista_nome) {
  if (lista_nome == "residencial") {
    var lista = residencial_lista;
  }

  if (lista_nome == "comercial") {
    var lista = comercial_lista;
  }

  if (lista_nome == "rural") {
    var lista = rural_lista;
  }

  if (lista_nome == "lazer") {
    var lista = lazer_lista;
  }

  var select_alvo = document.forms[formulario_nome][select_nome];
  select_alvo.options.length = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    var nome_opcao = lista[i];
    select_alvo.options[i] = new Option(nome_opcao);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="inicio('formimoveis', 'selecao', 'residencial')">
  <form name="formimoveis" method="post" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Residencial" onClick="trocarSelect('formimoveis', 'selecao', 'residencial');" checked /> Residencial
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Comercial" onClick="trocarSelect('formimoveis', 'selecao', 'comercial');" /> Comercial
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Rural" onClick="trocarSelect('formimoveis', 'selecao', 'rural');" /> Rural
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Lazer" onClick="trocarSelect('formimoveis', 'selecao', 'lazer');" /> Lazer
    <br />

    <select name="selecao">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
  </form>
</body>
```

Seria perfeito se ao invés do campo input `type="radio"` fosse um `<select>`.

Quais alterações tenho que fazer para fazer essa mudança?

Answer (score 0):

Basta trocar os `radios` por este `select`:

```
<select onchange="trocarSelect('formimoveis', 'selecao', this.value);">
   <option value="residencial">Residencial</option>
   <option value="comercial">Comercial</option>
   <option value="rural">Rural</option>
   <option value="lazer">Lazer</option>
</select>
```

Terá o mesmo efeito no `onchange` que os `radios` tinham ao serem clicados..